# Negating an Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have a function that returns an expression, I pass in a field and a value.  I have the function returning StartsWith, but I want to return NOT StartsWith

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GenerateFieldDoesNotStartsWithExpression<T>(string fieldName, string value) {
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "i");
    var fieldAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, fieldName);
    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var passedValue = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
    var body = Expression.Call(fieldAccess, method, passedValue);
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    return expr;
}
```

Returns `i.[fieldName].StartsWith(value)` but i'm looking for
`!i.[fieldName].StartsWith(value)`.

I've tried a few things such as setting `parameter = !i` and a second parameter as `i`, but then I get "parameter '!i' was not bound".

I tried messing around with Expression.Not, and couldn't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Show us the code you were using with `Expression.Not`, and explain, specifically what did not work.

Comment: I wasn't really sure what to pass to Expression.Not, nor where to do so.
tried passing the parameter (unable to convert)
parameter = Expression.Not(parameter);
Tried passing the resulting expression (unable to convert)
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
expr = Expression.Not(expr)

Comment: The documentation will tell you what you should be passing to it, and it also has examples.  You call it on whatever expression you want to get an expression representing the logical inverse of.

Comment: Seems I want to apply it to the passedValue

var passedValue = Expression.Not(Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string)));

I get Not is not defined for System.String

Comment: That is correct, you cannot NOT a string.  You can only NOT a boolean value.  Which of the expressions that you have represent an expression that generates a boolean value?

Comment: Okay, got it!  var body = Expression.Not(...)  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround you `Expression.Call` with `Expression.Not`

```
var body = Expression.Not(Expression.Call(fieldAccess, method, passedValue));
```

Your Code:

```
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GenerateFieldDoesNotStartsWithExpression<T>(string fieldName, string value)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "i");
        var fieldAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, fieldName);
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
        var passedValue = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
        // Wrapped Expression.Call with Expression.Not
        var body = Expression.Not(Expression.Call(fieldAccess, method, passedValue));
        var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return expr;
    }
```

Test Code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExpressNotTests
{
    [Test]
    public void GenerateFieldDoesNotStartsWithExpression_DoesNotStartWith_True()
    {
        var a = new TestClass() {TestString = "Not"};

        var exp = GenerateFieldDoesNotStartsWithExpression<TestClass>("TestString", "Test");

        var res = exp.Compile()(a);

        res.Should().BeTrue();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GenerateFieldDoesNotStartsWithExpression_DoesStartsWith_False()
    {
        var a = new TestClass() {TestString = "TestString"};

        var exp = GenerateFieldDoesNotStartsWithExpression<TestClass>("TestString", "Test");

        var res = exp.Compile()(a);

        res.Should().BeFalse();
    }


    private class TestClass
    {
        public string TestString { get; set; }
    }
}
```